# Display in-display fingerprint sensor animation

Tags: java, android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I create an application that use biometric authentification. 
Like you know Oneplus published new smartphone with in-display fingerprint sensor (OnePlus 6t). 
I would like display the animation of fingerprint sensor when I use fingerprint manager, like this :
[OnePlus 6t fingerprint animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O8au.png).

I know that some applications do it but I didn't find any publication about this. 
Did you know how do this ?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: You're supposed to use `BiometricPrompt` nowadays. When you do that, the system will take care of showing the authentication UI for you.

Comment: Yes, I should be. But which is the equivalent of hasEnrolledFingerprints() with BiometricPrompt ? Because it seems that doesn't exist.

Comment: It depends. If you need to check for that without potentially triggering an authentication you might have to use `hasEnrolledFingerprints` for that part. Obviously that only checks for enrolled fingerprints, and not for any other types of biometrics. If you're ok with finding out when you try to start an authentication you can check for `ERROR_NO_BIOMETRICS` in `onAuthenticationError`.